# Getting the all the cell values belongs to one column in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get all the values in one particular column in a table and check each value against the value im inputting in a textbox using Jquery ,and if any of the values in that column is higher than the input value i need to display a warning message .

For the moment i have this code which is working fine but my table ( which is a dynamic table generated by ajax) has many row's and there is a chance that user might not notice the highlighted row . so is there way to replace this with a warning message box ?

my code

```
$('#input1').on('change', function() {       
        var  val1 = parseInt($('#input1').val());            
        $(".btable td.single").filter(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text()) < val1;
       }).parent().addClass('highlite');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this that you want?

```
$('#input1').on('change', function() {       
    var  val1 = parseInt($('#input1').val());            
  let count = $(".btable td.single").filter(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) > val1;
  }).length;
  if(count > 0) {
    alert(count + ' values are greater than input!');
  }
});
```

This displays an alert instead of highlighting the rows.

Hope it helps

Comment: ah yes , excellent , i never thought of that , thanks you so much